# How to change font size in Angular Materials mat-chip (2023)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the font-size in a <mat-chip> without using CSS bodges, which don't appear to work or be predictable, but using the correct typography within Angular Materials. Does anyone know how to do it properly?

```
.mat-chip {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

as some posters have suggested, doesn't work, and typography is a mystery and even Angular can't document it properly.

Comment: [Customizing Typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) and [stackblitz of your css](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pf8kxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Comment: I see it, but for some reason my CSS is just being ignored. The chips in the examples on the Material pages also show that colors of primary and alert change the chip colours. Mine are simply grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typography is in no way a mystery and the documentation of css is not part of angulars documentation rather css's individual one.

### To debug css

Preview your code in a browser and in the inspect tool you will find all the css applied to your specific element. Find out how to create higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on your custom selector and do that in your code. Try not to use !important it's bad for code maintainibility. Also `.` is a class selector and things enclosed with `<>` are elements. Just delete the dot you should be fine (as long as there is no css of higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

### Angualr specific mentions

If `mat-chip` is a component check out the `:host` selector it selects the components element itself.

Comment: Solved in the end. Thanks to guidance here.

Comment: An upvote would be apreciated

Comment: In the end, I managed to do it with:
.mat-mdc-standard-chip {
    --mdc-chip-label-text-size: 12px;
    --mdc-chip-label-text-font: 'Open Sans';
    --mdc-chip-container-height: 25px;
    --mdc-chip-elevated-container-color: rgb(221, 163, 163);
}
@media (max-width: 1500px) {
    .mat-mdc-standard-chip {
        --mdc-chip-label-text-size: 8px;
    }
}